# Any example of GMSCALayer usage?

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

There are no examples of how to add a GMSCALayer or GMSMapLayer to a GMSMapView.

I am assuming it should be something along the lines:

```
var layer1 = GMSCALayer(layer: pulsator)
    layer1.map = viewMap
```

Or is the GMSCALayer something that can't be instantiated?

Comment: You don't create them yourself.  You can get the `GMSMapLayer` that's attached to an existing `GMSMapView` through the `layer` property.

Comment: I appreciate your response!